# accessing remote server with name instead of ip address and port number

Tags: networking, webserver, remote, hosts-file, tomcat

I have question regarding accessing my web application with some name,which is deployed on remote server.

Currently, I using following URL

```
http://160.110.67.181:8080/myapp
```

So, I'm wondering instead of above url, if user could access my application like

```
http://mytool.com/myapp
```

Then, it will be very good.

I tried editing `hosts` file on remote server. But, it didn't helped.

```
160.110.67.181:8080 mytool.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the port number from your entry

The `hosts` file only resolves an ip address to a host or an alias of a host. Name resolution does not know or care about ports. Only the browser application cares about the port number.

You can then use `http://mytool.com:8080/myapp` to access the site. If the remote server was running on port 80 you could eliminate the port number from the URL for common web access.

Comment: Ok. Thats works.But, I have 2 questions

1. If I want to hide my port number of web app. Then how do I do this ?
2. Webserver is on remote machine,which means if user has to access my app, either he/she has to edit their `hosts` file or directly use ip address. Is there any way, by which they do not require to change their `hosts` file and even though, they can access my app on `LAN`

Comment: There is a way and that is to purchase a domain and point an A record to the IP address. There are free options for such domains but they won't be a tier 1 *.com domain. If you have a dynamic ip then you will need to use a dynamic update client to a service which supports it.

Comment: If you need access to the app only inside your local network, you can also set up a local DNS server, and then tell your local network DHCP server to give that DNS server's address to users.